# Is this usage of the term 'Jacobian' related to the other uses e.g. matrix or elliptic function?

Tags: inversive-geometry

In the inversive geometry exercise below (from Geometry Revisited by Coxeter and Greitzer), the solution refers to the point pair $(L, O)$ as the Jacobian of the two point pairs $AC$ and $BD$. I was (and am) vaguely aware of at least two other "Jacobian's": the (I'm quoting Wikipedia here) matrix of all first order partial differentials of a vector valued function and; 2) Jacobian elliptic functions. The exercise follows, but my question is simply if these (and possibly other) uses of the term Jacobian is only because of the common link being the mathematician Carl Gustav Jacobi, or is there some deeper link relating these concepts?

Here is the problem I referred to and my rendition of the book's solution:

Any four distinct points A, B, C, D can be inverted into the vertices of a parallelogram $A'B'C'D'$ (including, as one possibility, a degenerate parallelogram in which the four vertices lie on one line, but still $A'B' = D'C'$ and $A'D' = B'C'$). Hint: Consider separately the three cases (i) $AC // BD$; (ii) $AB // CD$ or $AD // BC$; (iii) A, B, C, D not concyclic.

The case of interest with respect to Coxeter and Greitzer's use of the term 'Jacobian' is the third. The diagrams below give my rendition of the book's solution for this case:

[image: Exercise 5.7.6]

[image: 5.7.6 supplementary]

[image: 5.7.6 Lemma]

Comment: In fact, I have found a 1968 article of Coxeter in the Mathematical Gazette entitled "Midcircles and Loxodromes" https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/midcircles-and-loxodromes/F21742CE476197EB1859A65D1E5DF2E1 where, in the last page, he justifies why he uses the term "Jacobian" : it is indeed a true "Jacobian" with the meaning it has in analysis.

Comment: Article ref just what I wanted for that answer - thank you !!